# Expandable ListView change childdata on buttonClick

Tags: java, android, button, expandablelistview, onclicklistener

Okay, my English is not the best, but I will give it a try :)

I have three buttons, each one implements an `OnClickListener`. I have an `ExpandableListView`, filled with data. If one button is clicked, I would like to call the method which changes the child data and to show the new data changed by the method. The problem is that the data remains the same and there are no changes. I also tried to call the method `notifyDataSetChanged` in the `onClick` method but it does not work.

```
    [...]

    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    dienstag.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arrayDienstagInitialsierung();
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);


    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

private void arrayDienstagInitialsierung() {
    System.out.println("hallo bin im dienstag drinnen");
    //Früchstück
    for (int f = 0;f < zwischenTabelleListe.size();f++)
    {
        if(zwischenTabelleListe.get(f).getMahlzeit().equals("Fruechstueck")
           && zwischenTabelleListe.get(f).getTag() == 2) //kommt noch dazu welcher ernährungsplan geplant ist
        {

produkteListeFruechstueckString.add(produkteListe.get(fr).toString());  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your questions in English

Comment: okay, my english is not the best, but i will give it a try :). i have three buttons, each one implements an onclicklistener. i have an expendable listview, filled with data. my wish is to after i click on a button to call the method(which changes the childdata) and to show the new data changed by the method. the problem is the data remain always the same and there are no changes. i also tried to call the method notifyDataSetChanged in the onClick method but it does not work

Comment: Thank you. I think it is hard to answer your question if you do not show any code. Could you please edit your original question and insert your existing code?

Comment: i can not, because i am new here and i need some points or sth like that. the main problem is that i can not refresh the data. i wrote a system.out.println(the childdatalist) and the result is correct, so i called the method in the onClick method and a line beyond i have wrotten adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: okay now you can see the relevant code

Comment: Ty. I have edited your post so the question is clear to everyone. To solve your issue you also have to add the code of the method `arrayDienstagInitialisierung()` and the definition of `listAdapter`.